# Can't move components WindowBuilder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm building a project on Eclipse's window builder but when I try to move my JLabel on top of the JButtons so it can be seen, it rarely allows me. I get lucky once in a while and moved some labels on top of the buttons but it usually never works. I can easily move the JButtons and arrange them the way I want but the labels never work. Any help would be appreciated.

Components List:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUkhz.png]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to move that label and put it above your button?

Comment: Which Eclipse and WindowBuilder versions do you have? Is this Windows, Linux or macOS? If Linux, please tell also the GTK version.